# Exoplayer takes 10x start time for exact same HLS stream in same device and same bandwidth

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have been making a video application, where I am using Exoplayer to stream HLS video content.

Exoplayer is working fine as long as the device is connected to Wifi. When connected to wifi it is taking 1-2 sec start time.

However, when switched to mobile data, for the exact same video(same URI), from the same device sometimes exoplayer is starting the playback in 1 sec, and sometimes it starts the playback after 10 seconds with no error.

For e.g the first time you play it, it will start in 1 second, then you go back, open the player activity again, and try to play,  it will now take 10-15seconds.

However, if you try playing it again after 5-10 mins, it will start in 1-2 seconds.

Everything works fine when connected to Wifi though.

If you can please help.

Here's the URL of the video https://d2w8ntyqaeyvg.cloudfront.net/HLS/8pv1p456kdgghmxki.m3u8